Shopware 6 - can't see the subscriptions settings
as shown in the documentation of Shopware 6, there must be a link in Settings > Shop > Subscriptions. But I can't find it. What do I have to enable, to get the subscription feature in my Shopware 6.6.4.1 project?
Is it perhaps because the feature is only delivered via a composer component?
I have already tried to activate the "feature", but with the following command I could neither see nor activate the subscription feature:
bin/console  feature:list

[INFO] All features that are registered:                                                                               
                                                                                                                        

 ---------------------- ---------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------- 
  Code                   Name                   Description                                                                                                        Status    
 ---------------------- ---------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------- 
  V6_5_0_0               V6_5_0_0                                                                                                                                  Enabled   
  V6_6_0_0               V6_6_0_0                                                                                                                                  Enabled   
  V6_7_0_0               V6_7_0_0                                                                                                                                  Disabled  
  DISABLE_VUE_COMPAT     DISABLE_VUE_COMPAT                                                                                                                        Disabled  
  ACCESSIBILITY_TWEAKS   ACCESSIBILITY_TWEAKS   Accessibility tweaks (highly recommended)                                                                          Disabled  
                                                Accessibility improvements can alter the HTML and CSS structure of the template.                                             
                                                The accessibility improvements will be standard as of v6.7.0                                                                 
  ADMIN_VITE             ADMIN_VITE             Experimental! Uses Vite instead of webpack to built and serve the administration. Plugins are not yet supported!   Disabled  
 ---------------------- ---------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------- 


That didn't work either:
bin/console  feature:enable SUBSCRIPTION

Feature "SUBSCRIPTION" is not registered. 


Since the docs you are referring to stating: "The Subscriptions feature is available from version 6.5.4.0.
It is available as a Commercial feature from the Beyond plan." I assume you have a Beyond plan and the Commercial Plugin is installed and activated?

Oh my god. Thank you very much! I simply overlooked the info box. Thank you!
